# Skype & Cheese video

Tags: video, skype, webcam, cheese

I cannot view the webcam in Skype or Cheese.

The webcam is working because it is viewable on the Skype call at the other end and Cheeses will take photos. Also I cannot view any incoming videos in Skype.

Ubuntu 10.04
Fujitsu Amilo L7300
Video card - Via CN400/PM800/PM8080/PN800/PN880 S3 UniChrome Pro

---

I have tried Guvcview & Skype 4, but did not improve things.

Output from lsusb and lspci are:

```
lsusb
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05c7:0113 Qtronix Corp. PC Line Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:628f Microdia PC Camera with Microphone (SN9C202 + OV9650)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. CN333/CN400/PM880 Host Bridge
00:00.1 Host bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. CN333/CN400/PM880 Host Bridge
00:00.2 Host bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. CN333/CN400/PM880 CPU Host Bridge
00:00.3 Host bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. CN333/CN400/PM880 Host Bridge
00:00.4 Host bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. CN333/CN400/PM880 Host Bridge
00:00.7 Host bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. CN333/CN400/PM880 Host Bridge
00:01.0 PCI bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT8237/VX700 PCI Bridge
00:06.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88w8335 [Libertas] 802.11b/g Wireless (rev 43)
00:0c.0 CardBus bridge: ENE Technology Inc CB1410 Cardbus Controller (rev 01)
00:10.0 USB Controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT82xxxxx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev 80)
00:10.1 USB Controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT82xxxxx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev 80)
00:10.3 USB Controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. USB 2.0 (rev 82)
00:11.0 ISA bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT8235 ISA Bridge
00:11.1 IDE interface: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT82C586A/B/VT82C686/A/B/VT823x/A/C PIPC Bus Master IDE (rev 06)
00:11.5 Multimedia audio controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT8233/A/8235/8237 AC97 Audio Controller (rev 50)
00:11.6 Communication controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. AC'97 Modem Controller (rev 80)
00:12.0 Ethernet controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6102 [Rhine-II] (rev 74)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. CN400/PM800/PM880/PN800/PN880 [S3 UniChrome Pro] (rev 02)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88w8335 [Libertas] 802.11b/g Wireless (rev 03)
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `lsusb` and `lspci` to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Cheese seems having some bugs.

Try **Guvcview**

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-ppa-repositories/18693-install-guvcview-gtk-uvc-viewer-to-ubuntu-1204-via-ppa-

Guvcview aims at providing a simple GTK interface for capturing and viewing video from devices supported by the linux UVC driver, although it should also work with any v4l2 compatible device.

Install **Guvcview** to Ubuntu via ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pj-assis/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install guvcview
```

---

For **skype** try this ppa

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-ppa-repositories/17253-ubuntu-1204-skype-40-ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/chat

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install skype
```